# Need files off a remote server... best way to get them?

Tags: download, ftp

Was initially trying FTP, but the server doesn't seem to like me very much - it'll go through a bunch of directories, noting that it's already downloaded some of the files, all good. After a few seconds of this, the FTP server becomes unresponsive. Clearly, not a grand solution - but it's somewhat out of my control, since it's a shared host doing this.

Is there a better way to access the files at this point? Or should I just keep trying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what the server supports.  If SSH is an option, you could use SCP/SFTP/rsync or any number of GUI clients for those protocols.  HTTP is another potential option.

But if the server only supports FTP, you could try using a different FTP client to connect.

If you're using a wireless connection, try a wired connection to avoid the potential for interference.  Worst case, use a different internet connection to try to avoid problems along the route -- if your cable modem isn't getting it, the neighbor's DSL might.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that my wi-fi signal was fluctuating; plugged into wired and now I seem good to go.

Sorry for the false alarm, but I'd definitely appreciate - for future users - other ways of acquiring files if FTP begins to fail.

Comment: quack's answer still stands - it depends on what the server supports. If FTP is the only protocol allowed than there's just no other option.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) if it's possible.  You can easily continue copying the files if you get disconnected.

rsync -vurt --progress username@some_host:/home/username/a_dir /home/me/backups